# Angularfire2 The custom token format is incorrect

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire, angularfire2

I'm generating token and passing to Angularfire2, it keep giving me:

```
The custom token format is incorrect
```

while the same token works fine on Angular1 Firebase .

```
    constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    let token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhZG1pbiI6ZmFsc2UsImRlYnVnIjpmYWxzZSwiZXhwIjoxNDkwODAwOTYzLCJkIjp7InVpZCI6Im1heGllLGZlZW5leSJ9LCJ2IjowLCJpYXQiOjE0NzUxNjI1NjN9.YAyRVxL6dlw4WCVHY8lCd09qJ2tY9rg_dTQZtkW5zAs';

    af.auth.login(token, {})
        .then((success) => {
          console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
  }
```

Does anyone know what difference is with Angular2 token, which is different from Angular1 Firebase token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your token is a [valid jwt token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens), which it probably is since it worked before, you can authenticate with the custom token with extra parameters passed into login.

```
af.auth.login(token, {
  provider: AuthProviders.Custom,
  method: AuthMethods.CustomToken
})
.then(...)
.catch(...);
```

For more specific details of other available login parameters you can view the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts).

If this doesn't work, you might have to take a deeper look at how you are forming your jwt token. I can help you with that too.